# Is Bruce referring to Superman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Steppenwolf took the Mother Box from the Amazons, and hid it near the toxic chimneys. Then Bruce Wayne is shown shaving his beard, while Alfred is sitting in a chair and watching CCTV footage from a grocery store:

> Bruce Wayne: This has nothing to do with Lex Luthor. It has to do with
> **him**. I made a promise to him on his grave. I spent a lot of time trying to divide us. I need to bring us together and make this right.

Is "him" a reference to Superman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

It's a reference to the events of the previous film, *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*. In particular the final scene has Bruce at Superman's grave.